# Garlic Quick Pickle Too Spicy

Tags: garlic, pickles

I'm trying to make garlic flavored quick/refrigerator pickles, but when I simply try to increase the amount of garlic in the jars, they end up getting fairly spicy. I am using some red pepper flake, but not much.

I've had store bought garlic pickles that just have a garlic flavor without the bite. Is there a way to make my pickles more "garlicky" without getting the extra spiciness from the garlic?

Comment: Is your garlic cooked at all? Can you tell if the commercial ones were?

Comment: Can you tell us your method? Garlic's aggressive 'front' backs off if exposed to the air an hour or two after crushing.

Answer (score 3):

Store-bought pickles are most likely, at minimum, cooked in canning them for shelf-stable storage.

"Roasting" (so-called, it's more like steaming in the oven with a little caramelization, as typical recipes are done in foil or a foil-covered dish) garlic for a short time will mellow it a great deal. Longer times have greater effects.

Cooking it somewhat any other way will also affect (reduce) the raw-garlic "bite."